# Load .qlr with loadNamedStyle

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qlr

I tried

```
>>>QgsVectorLayer.loadNamedStyle(r'C:\Some\Path\FOO.qlr')
```

Get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QgsVectorLayer.loadNamedStyle(QString, bool) -> (QString, bool): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QgsVectorLayer'
  QgsVectorLayer.loadNamedStyle(QString) -> (QString, bool): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QgsVectorLayer'
```

Then i tried:

```
>>>vlayer = QgsVectorLayer
>>>vlayer = loadNamedStyle(r'C:\Some\Path\FOO.qlr')
```

and gets the same error.
The question is simple. How do i load a .qlr-file from path?

My research:
[The developers archive,](http://qgis-developer.osgeo.narkive.com/7OFZtxGN/how-to-load-a-qlr-file-with-pyqgis)
[The C++  documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aad6d52784c29b5fe02949fd5679d3623) (which i suppose is good but I don't know C++),
[Some one with a similar problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142545/pyqgis-load-qlr-files)

I have a hard time finding Api for the py qgis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### QGIS 2.x

The [source file for layer definitions](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/qgslayerdefinition.cpp#L33) indicates that you need to use `loadLayerDefinition` and not `loadNamedStyle`. Therefore we need to
specify a string path and a [QgsLayerTreeGroup](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeGroup.html) in which the layer will be loaded into. Then we can either:

- Create a new empty group in the Table of Contents:

  ```
  root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
  group = root.addGroup("group1")
  QgsLayerDefinition().loadLayerDefinition('C:/Some/Path/FOO.qlr', group)
  ```
- Or use an existing group:

  ```
  root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
  group = root.findGroup('group1')
  QgsLayerDefinition().loadLayerDefinition('C:/Some/Path/FOO.qlr', group)
  ```

---

### QGIS 3.x

The [QgsLayerDefinition().loadLayerDefinition()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerDefinition.html#a04716c6e6606b6f5f6af4193e6cf6a38) function now requires the project instance as an input parameter. So the last line of each of the above code snippets can be replaced from:

```
QgsLayerDefinition().loadLayerDefinition('C:/Some/Path/FOO.qlr', group)
```

to:

```
QgsLayerDefinition().loadLayerDefinition('C:/Some/Path/FOO.qlr', QgsProject.instance(), group)
```

Comment: Yes I have loaded the .qlr file from path.

Comment: How do I draw the group? Nothing shows upp in the map.

Comment: @VilyaSeeFour - For me, the layers are already drawn. You can right-click the group and choose the `Zoom to Group` to make sure the canvas is looking at the right area :)

Comment: turned out I needed to have the strings raw or wit dubble backlashes. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: @VilyaSeeFour - Glad you got it working! Yes, I prefer using single forward slashes to avoid those kinds of problems :)

Comment: @Joseph is this different now in Qgis 3x? I get TypeError: QgsLayerDefinition.loadLayerDefinition(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 2 has unexpected type 'QgsLayerTreeGroup'
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'

Comment: @GeorgeC - Thanks for your comment, I've edited the post. You just need to add the project instance as a secondary parameter. I.e. `QgsLayerDefinition().loadLayerDefinition('C:/Some/Path/FOO.qlr', QgsProject.instance(), group)`

Comment: @Joseph -this is loading the file but I am getting an issue on load where the data is not loading properly.See https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EN9v.jpg

Comment: @GeorgeC - I would suggest you ask this as a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and include as much detail as possible including what you saved in your .qlr file and the type of layer you are applying it to.

Comment: @Joseph see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314713/qlr-loaded-via-pyqgis-not-loading-correctly-but-works-when-using-layer-add-qlr