# QLR loaded via PyQGIS not loading correctly but works when using layer--add qlr

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qlr

Based on [Load .qlr with loadNamedStyle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240691/load-qlr-with-loadnamedstyle/240694?noredirect=1#comment511469_240694) I was able to add a QLR to a python tool via PyQGIS -however, it appears broken...

```
            elif ftype=='qlr':
                try:
                    print ('Loading QLR layer')
                    #ref:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240691/load-qlr-with-loadnamedstyle/240694?noredirect=1#comment511181_240694
                    print("QLR %s called and loading into group %s" % (filePath, fname))
                    root=QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
                    print('adding group')
                    group=root.addGroup(fname)
                    QgsLayerDefinition().loadLayerDefinition(filePath,QgsProject.instance(),group)
                except:
                    print ('Error loading QLR')
```

fname is the name of the group and file, filepath is the path/file.qlr

The QLR is loading a shp that's in the same folder.

It looks like

```
 <!DOCTYPE qgis-layer-definition>
<qlr>
  <layer-tree-group checked="Qt::Checked" name="" expanded="1">
    <customproperties/>
    <layer-tree-layer id="events_6d4a5418_1dce_4ba0_201903071250415994831" checked="Qt::Checked" name="events" source="./events.shp" providerKey="ogr" expanded="1">
      <customproperties/>
    </layer-tree-layer>
  </layer-tree-group>
  <maplayers>
    <maplayer autoRefreshEnabled="0" labelsEnabled="1" refreshOnNotifyMessage="" maxScale="0" minScale="1e+08" hasScaleBasedVisibilityFlag="0" readOnly="0" styleCategories="AllStyleCategories" autoRefreshTime="0" type="vector" simplifyDrawingTol="1" refreshOnNotifyEnabled="0" simplifyDrawingHints="0" simplifyAlgorithm="0" simplifyLocal="1" simplifyMaxScale="1" geometry="Point">
      <extent>
        <xmin>142.5193149000000119</xmin>
        <ymin>-37.29052469999999886</ymin>
        <xmax>143.2661899999999946</xmax>
        <ymax>-36.60563100000000247</ymax>
      </extent>
      <id>events_6d4a5418_1dce_4ba0_201903071250415994831</id>
      <datasource>./events.shp</datasource>
      <keywordList>
        <value></value>
      </keywordList>
      <layername>events</layername>
```

and it comes out like [image]

However...

It works fine if I load it in the QGIS python console using the same commands...
[image]

Note screen grabs are of a complex and simple QLR I tried but both end up the same...